# scrollTo or localscroll not working on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, scrollto

I have a series of js files working on my (soon) new site. I am using scrollTo.js and localscroll.js to on a single page solution. In  addition I have a drop-down menu that also uses another .js file and targets specific '#'s'. This combination of scripts work fine on every browser (including IE7) however on IE8, loses its target and barely makes it to half of the page. sometimes links randomly go back to the top. Here is the link: http://www.oscarcreates.com/OSKR/Index.html if you don't mind taking a look and giving me some pointers. All help is well appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I realized on IE8, when you click home before any other nav link, it actually takes you to the correct "#". It's like home is the reset default for the links to work.